# Error while serializing datetime property

Tags: vb.net, wcf

When i include datetime property in object and return it in wcf service then it gives error status 12152. Without datetime property in my object it works fine. Datetime property content is #1/22/2016 12:08:36 PM#. 
How to make it work with datetime property?

wcf call

```
function populateEditAuditResultData(AuditID) {
        CallWCFService('DataService.svc/GetAuditCase',
        '{"AuditID": "' + AuditID + '"}',
        function (result) { //success

        },
        function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { //failure

        }
    );
}
```

wcf service

```
<OperationContract()> _
Public Function GetAuditCase(ByVal AuditID As Integer) As AuditCase
    Return New AuditCase(AuditID)
End Function
```

constructor

```
Public Sub New(ByVal AuditID As String)
    Me.AuditID = AuditID
    Me.GetData()
End Sub
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim conn = New DatabaseConnection()
    Dim params = New List(Of SqlParameter)
    If AuditID <> Nothing Then params.Add(New SqlParameter("AuditID", Me.AuditID))
    Dim table = conn.RunSprocQuery(ReferenceData.prc_GetAuditCaseDetails, params.ToArray())
    If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ReadAuditCase(table.Rows(0), Me)
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Sub ReadAuditCase(ByVal row As DataRow, ByRef AudCase As AuditCase, Optional ByVal IncludeOptionalFields As Boolean = True)
    AudCase.AuditID = CInt(row("AuditID"))
    AudCase.AuditTypeID = CInt(row("AuditTypeID"))
    AudCase.AllocationOn = Convert.ToDateTime(row("AllocationOn"))   
End Sub
```

Comment: **Show your code.!**

Comment: Code added. Please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved the problem by changing the time zone to UTC.
Alternatively it can be solved by using following code.

```
AudCase.AllocationOn = Convert.ToDateTime(row("AllocationOn")).ToUniversalTime()
```

Hope this help others.